# how is possible to change the order of printed divs in a main div?

Tags: php, html, css

i have a div with id messages that is supposed to keep messages of a conversation. i like when i fetch messages from database newest messages be on bottom of div. but they appear on top! how can i change their order?
for instance:

```
 $query = "SELECT `messageID`,`message`,`submitDate`
 FROM `messages`
 ORDER BY `submitDate` DESC LIMIT 0, 4";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) ;
print('<div id="messages">');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   print('<div id="'.$row['messageID'].'">'.$row['message'].'</div>');
}
print('</div>');
```

message 4 is newest. but the problem is when i use mysql_fetch_array() function the newest printed on top. like this:

Message 4

Message 3

Message 2

Message 1

Comment: Your query sorts the data by date in descending order, i.e. the most recent messages first. You need to reverse this by changing `ORDER BY submitDate DESC` to `ORDER BY submitDate ASC`.

Comment: So you want the newest/last 4 messages, but in `ASC` not `DESC` order?

Comment: Sean: yes. i want 4 last messages. but i want to show top/down. i mean newst message be in bottom of div. like what we have in viber , whats app and ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store your new information so you can build the way you want...

```
 $query = "SELECT `messageID`,`message`,`submitDate`
 FROM `messages`
 ORDER BY `submitDate` DESC LIMIT 0, 4";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) ;
print('<div id="messages">');
$divs = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $divs = '<div id="'.$row['messageID'].'">'.$row['message'].'</div>'.$divs;
}
print($divs);
print('</div>');
```

Comment: why post a 2nd answer, and not just edit your 1st. Also, how is this different than what the OP has? All you are doing is saving to a variable, and then printing that variable without reordering.

Comment: It most certainly is reordering it because the latest value is now being added before the previous values instead of after them.  It would not be reordering if the line was $divs = $divs.'<div id="'.$row['messageID'].'">'.$row['message'].'</div>'; but its not. Not sure why I didn't just edit the other answer...sorry.

Comment: yeap, sorry I missed your `$divs` at the end

Comment: tnx . but i didnt changed the order! :/

Comment: Strange, it most certainly should since you are reversing the order of the divs using this method.  Are you sure you used $divs = '<div id="'.$row['messageID'].'">'.$row['message'].'</div>'.$divs; as suggested and not $divs .= '<div id="'.$row['messageID'].'">'.$row['message'].'</div>'; or some other derivative?

Comment: oh sorry! no i didnt understood it at first! it works great. thank you very much :)) it was really good trick ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the sort order of your query from DESC to ASC

Comment: tnx but if i change so i can not have the last messages!

Comment: OK, missed that you were limiting to 4...sorry

Answer (score 0):

as DanielM already wroted, your ordering in the sql-query is wrong.

But $row is an array, so you can also change just the ordering of this array by using  http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: tnx. but it needs more procces. there is no other way to do it with css or html?

Answer (score 0):

As you want the newest 4 messages, but in `ASC` order, you will need to do a subquery first to get the 4 `messageID`s, and then order them in `ASC` order -

```
$query = "SELECT `messageID`,`message`,`submitDate`
 FROM `messages`
 WHERE `messageID` IN (
        SELECT `messageID` FROM `messages` ORDER BY `submitDate` DESC LIMIT 0, 4)
 ORDER BY `submitDate` ASC";
```